# How to display a linked URL when using Rinku? (Rails Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the Rinku rails gem to make URLs linked in any content posted on my website.

I've installed and implemented it but the problem is that the HTML code shows in the view.

Here's a code that I'm using

```
<%= truncate(Rinku.auto_link(feed_item.content), :length=>400, :omission=>' ...(next page)') %>
```

Here's a sample output view on my website

```
hey guys check out my website at <a href="http://www.someURL.com">www.someURL.com</a>
```

As you can see, the HTML `<a>` tags show. What does feed_item.content should be change to for this to work correctly?

Feed_item.content is a text, not a string. It appears that Rinku parses string. Is that the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by default, Rails will escape any html in a string you output in erb (using `<%= %>`) as a precautionary measure. (If you look at the page source, you should see that your output looks like `&lt;a ...&gt;` instead of `<a ...>`.)

To stop this from happening, you can use the `.html_safe` method to mark that the string is safe to print as html:

```
<%= truncate(...).html_safe %>
```

Comment: that seemed to work, but any idea why it interferes with the "delete" link that I have? The delete code is "<%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete %> and it seems to not work after .html_safe added

Comment: You mean you added `.html_safe` to that `link_to`? There's no need to do so, `link_to` and the other helpers that generate html already call `.html_safe` on the returned string.